# logEvent of firebase have limit of characters on parameters, how i can send more of 100 characters to google analytics?

Tags: firebase, react-native, analytics, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

i need send analytics logEvent for google analytics with more off 100 characters on parameters. I using react-native-firebase for react-native and give me an error on debugView. So, someone know other solution for this case?

I try find others lib but no success.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to log events with more than 100 parameters, even upgrading to paid plans. The limits are the same for all Firebase projects. See this [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506?hl=en) for your reference.

Comment: Yes, i saw this. But my question is to use google-analytics without firebase to react-native.

Comment: I'm using react-native-google-analytics with some changes to send more of 100 characters. I removed react-native-firebase from my project.

react-native-google-analytics use js implementation to send information to google analytics.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference